# How to shadow a header file with CMake for unit-testing

Tags: c++, unit-testing, cmake

This is the simplified folder structure I have:

```
+ production
+-- ClassToTest.cpp (contains '#includes "DragonHeader.h"')
+-- ClassToTest.h
+-- DragonHeader.h (has a lot of dependencies, ClassToTest only need one simple static function with no dependencies at all.)
+ tests
+-- tst_ClassToTest.cpp
+-- DragonHeader.h (which defines and implements the needed simple function)
```

So for the test case I'd like that tests/DragonHeader.h shadows production/DragonHeader.h. => ClassToTest.cpp includes tests/DragonHeader.h. How can that be achieved? (I am working with MSVC 2015 if it is relevant...)

The CMakeLists.txt in the tests folder looks like

```
project( tst_ClassToTest )
set( ${PROJECT_NAME}_SOURCES tst_ClassToTest.cpp DragonHeader.h ../production/ClassToTest.cpp )
# How to force ClassToTest.cpp to use DragonHeader.h, not production/DragonHeader.h?
add_executable( ${PROJECT_NAME} WIN32 ${${PROJECT_NAME}_SOURCES} )
```

Thanks!

Disclaimer: I seek for a solution that does not require me to touch ClassToTest.cpp or to touch the code in production including the related CMakeLists.txt files at all. One solution, however, is to use CMake to copy ClassToTest.cpp/h into the tests folder, but I consider it sub-optimal.

Comment: Is the issue that DragonHeader.h requires other libraries that you don't want to respecify in the tests project? If that's true, try making the main project a library with a small executable that links it. Then the tests can link the library too. CMake makes this very easy, since the executables take include directories etc from the library, so you only have to mention it once.

Comment: The issue is somewhat unclear to me as well, could you add some more details on the problems you're facing?

Comment: The premise for my question is that I can not touch any file in "production" nor can I change the overall build process (that's what Joseph proposed). I know that it gets somewhat theoretical at this point, but that's what I am after: How to prevent a cpp file fetching a header file right beside itself. In contrast I'd like to plant an other header (with the same name, but different location) "into" the cpp file. While writing I realized that I want to change the inlcude directory order for the cpp file from ". tests" to "tests ." (note the ".").

Answer (score 1):

My first thought was to use different `include_directory` statements for both production and unit test. But in this case the other header file `ClassToTest.h` must be in a different folder. Or you have to  move`DragonHeader.h` into another folder.

```
# CMake for production
include_directory(production)
include_directory(production_dragon)

#CMake for test
include_directory(production)
include_directory(test_dragon)
```

Another way could be an

```
#ifndef USE_TEST_HEADERS
#include "DragonHeaderTest.h"
#else
#include "DragonHeader.h"
#endif
```

in `ClassToTest.cpp`. To set the define add  into your `test/CMakeLists.txt` file the string `-DUSE_TEST_HEADERS` to the compiler flags.

Third solution is to replace `production/DragonHeader.h` by a copy of `test/DragonHeader.h` in advanced of make. This works only in case `production/DragonHeader.h` can be restored. Either from a file system copy or from your Configuration Mgmt. System. This can by achieved by wrap the bild into a script. Don't know whether MSVC 2015 can trigger such a script instead of build.

```
rem Build for tests
rem Run cmake 
cmake PARAMETERS
rem Prepare unit test
cp WHATEVER
rem nmake
name PARAMETERS
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Both solutions will work just fine, I know, but the sticking point is that I can neither alter ClassToTest.cpp nor change any existing CMakeLists.txt. Take it as an academic question: How to prevent the C++ preprocessor/compiler from taking the header right beside ClassToTest.cpp and persuade the compiler to take /an/arbitrary/other/header.h.